# VScode not opening on ubuntu 23.10

Tags: bash, 23.10, visual-studio-code

I tried running vscode but when I write code . in bash or open vscode via the icon, VScode doesn't want to open anymore for some reason, To be more specific the vscode windows do open, but none of them are actually visible on my screen. When I hit alt + tab, I can clearly see that the directory has opened but no GUI is displayed.

For some context, this issue appeared after closing the window of one dir and then opening another dir with once again code . I have tried some solutions posted online to similar problems without any luck. I am writing this in the hopes that someone can help me out here, thanks in advance!

I ran it in debug mode bash -x code and got the following:

```bash
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ grep -qi Microsoft /proc/version
++ id -u
+ '[' 1000 = 0 ']'
+ '[' '!' -L code ']'
++ dirname code
+ VSCODE_PATH=./..
+ ELECTRON=./../code
+ CLI=./../resources/app/out/cli.js
+ ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1
+ ./../code ./../resources/app/out/cli.js
/usr/bin/code: line 62: ./../code: No such file or directory
+ exit 127
```

This is line 62 of /usr/bin/code:
[image line 62](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wovBG.png)

Comment: Have you tried the Windows+Arrow keys?

Comment: @DanielT you mean windows + arrow keys in terms of moving an app around on the screen? If so, yes and when vscode is selected via windows + tab or alt + tab key and I keep pressing windows + arrow key repeatedly quickly it sort of twitches and shows vscode instantaneously

Comment: @DanielT oh wow!... it seems that the problem was in the fact that I had an external monitor connected but then I disconnected it, and the os probably didn't recognize that and was still in the join display mode. I just connected the monitor and it appeared.